# How to convert column to rows

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have csv file contain on 6 columns like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

I need to convert this columns to rows to be like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6 6
7 7 7 7 7 7
8 8 8 8 8 8
```

How can do that please?

This is input
[image]

This is the output
[image]

Comment: Using pandas: `pd.read_csv("in_path.csv", " ").T.to_csv("out_path.csv", " ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import csv

with open("input.csv", "r") as f_in, open("output.csv", "w") as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=" ")
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=" ")

    writer.writerows(zip(*reader))
```

---

Contents of `input.csv`:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Contents of `output.csv` after the script run:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6 6
7 7 7 7 7 7
8 8 8 8 8 8
```

Comment: Why all my columns wrote in one row?

Comment: @oleva probably you need to specify your delimiter (is it space? `\t`?) correctly.

Comment: The same thing, my output be like this: 1234567812345678..... in the same  row

Comment: I posted the input and the output

Comment: @oleva How do you save the file? As `CSV`? Try to use `,` as delimiter

Comment: Yes, CSV file .

Comment: @oleva Then use `reader = csv.reader(f_in)` and `writer = csv.writer(f_out)` (without the `delimiter=` parameter)

Comment: Thank you so much but now I have empty rows for example: 
1 1 1 1 1 1
empty row 
2 2 2 2 2 2 
empty row 
3 3 3 3 3 3

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for a table pivot method

if you are using pandas , this will do the trick https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html